# ListAdapter / convertView and new thread to get images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-image, android-adapter

I have a `ListView`, which holds information about songs. Additional I want to add an cover image to the `ListView`.

Therefore I wrote an adapter. The main thing in this adapter is the following `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Map dataSet = mData.get(position);
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.artist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageListView);
        holder.title = (ScrollingTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.artist.setText((CharSequence) dataSet.get("artist"));
    holder.title.setText((CharSequence) dataSet.get("title"));
    holder.time.setText((CharSequence) dataSet.get("time"));

    GetImg gi = new GetImg(v, mContext);
    gi.start();

    return v;
}
```

You can see, that I use a `ViewHolder` for better performance. In the `GetImg` class, which extends `Thread`, I am downloading the image and setting the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView`.

Now I am getting the following issue. Sometimes, more than one child view in the `ListView` get the same image. Why?

When I don't use `convertView`, everything works fine, but not as fast as with `convertView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not create new threads to download images inside `getView()`. It's very difficult to manage the threads by that way. Instead, you could try these:

- Use a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to manage images.
- Use a [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) with [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) for the `ListView`.

*For example*, when the user scrolls to new items, you query for images. In the content provider, if the images are new, create new threads to download them. When done, you make "fake" insertion to let the loader reload data and assign the images to views.

Notes:

- Make sure to manage threads properly. There would be hundreds of items and you could create too many threads while the user was scrolling the list.
- Consider using "slow adapter" for the `ListView`. You can view the example at *[Android-SDK]/samples/android-xxx/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.java* (or in emulators, open the app *API Demos > Views > Lists > 13. Slow Adapter*).

To view a complete example (just an app *without* source code), you can try [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haibison.android.apps.files). I'm using above techniques and a "slow adapter" for displaying thumbnails of images and videos.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting distinct values for Artist, title and time from your dataSet. For your Image view you will have to to the same thing with the holder. Assuming that you have a dataSet with unique images for each view in your ListView you need to add the **setImageDrawable** method for your ImageView as well. Something like :

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(//access your dataSet for images from here //);
```

Comment: A parameter of the GetImg class is the View v. I get the ImageView from the view v in the GetImg class and set the Bitmap in this class.

Comment: And I even don't have the URL, neither the Bitmap in the dataset.

Comment: You could save the specific images for individual items in drawable. Keep a mapping of the song -> image in DB / Shared preferences. Then extract this info while populating the ListView in an Arraylist and access the arrayList containing the imageNames in the above line. I have done this in my application as well.